# Windows Phone 8.1 не работает Html5 GeoLocation

Tags: javascript, html5, gps, геолокация, windows-phone-8.1

Установлена Visual Studio 2015. Создал проект типа Javascript/Windows/Windows8/Universal. В манифесте выставил флажок `Location` в `Capabilities`.
Запускаю приложение на устройстве Windows Phone 8.1. При вызове функции `getCurrentPosition` срабатывает обработчик `errorHandler`:

```
function startLocationTracking() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showCurrentLocation, errorHandler);
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO
    }
}

function showCurrentLocation(position) {
    // TODO
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log("Error while retrieving current position. Error code: " + error.code + ", Message: " + error.message);
}
```

Код ошибки 1, текст

> This site does not have permission to use the Geolocation API.

На устройстве функция "Местоположение" включена. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?